# Is std::next for vector O(n) or O(1)?

Tags: c++

In C++11 I use `std::next` because If I want to change `vector` to `list`, I dont have to change the rest of code.

For `list`, `std::next` is O(n), because I need to iterate all elements. But how is it for a `vector`? I have found [this note on *cppreference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next#Complexity):

> However, if `InputIt` or `ForwardIt` additionally meets the requirements of [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), complexity is constant.

Does `vector` meet these requirements? And why "Legacy"?

Comment: "Constant" means `O(1)`.

Comment: I know that, but I dont know If it aplies to vector, since I dont understand LegacyRandomAccessIterator. Why Legacy?

Comment: @MartinPerry Follow the link? In the page you pull the quote from, the word "[LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)" is a *link* to an explanation about it. And for vectors, iterators are (legacy) random-access iterators (as you should be able to find out in the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) reference).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a plan of adding concepts (compile time type constraints) in C++20. The new standard is supposed to contain concepts like `InputIterator` or `RandomAccessIterator`. To distinguish between the concepts and the old trait-like requirements cppreference uses `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` and so on for pre-concept requirements and `RandomAccessIterator` and so for concept requirements.

And so yes, `std::vector::iterator` meets requirements of `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` and actually will be fulfilling `RandomAccessIterator` concept as well. This leads straight to conclusion that `std::next` called on `vector::iterator` has complexity O(1).

Answer (score 9):

> Does vector meet these requirements?

Yes, it does:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Quote: "iterator LegacyRandomAccessIterator"

> And why "Legacy"?

The existing iterators have been renamed "legacy" because of the upcoming C++ library feature called [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), which is a replacement for the current approach. Ranges will have new iterators. The existing ones will still be there, thus they're called "legacy."