# Is it O(NlogN) or O(N^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I am trying to solve a problem on BinarySearch.com:

> Given a list of integers nums sorted in ascending order and an integer k, return whether any two elements from the list add up to k. You may not use the same element twice.  Note: Numbers can be negative or 0.  This should be done in `O(1)` space.
> So for `nums = [1, 3, 5, 8]` and `k = 6`, answer should be `true`.

I know it can be done using two pointers, but I am learning binary search, so I came up with the following logic:

```cpp
bool solve(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) {
        auto loc=lower_bound(begin(nums), end(nums), k-nums[i]);
        if(loc!=nums.end()) {
            if(distance(nums.begin(), loc)!=i && *loc+nums[i]==k) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It gets accepted, but **what is the time complexity**?  I am not sure if it is `O(NlogN)` since I run binary search (an `O(logN)` algo) for each value in `nums`, or if it should be `O(N^2)` because when the `if` condition is true, I use `distance()`, which, as I understand, is an `O(n)` operation by itself.

Comment: @Someone: For a std::vector, `std::distance` is a constant-time operation.

Comment: @AndyG, cool, thanks!

Comment: Improvements: `*loc+nums[i]==k` is always true since you just found `*loc == k - nums[i]` by searching. You also don't need to search through the entire vector; start at `begin(nums) + i + 1`. This would also make your other condition unnecessary.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, sorry that was a typo.  I meant: "I run binary search (an O(logN) algo) N times).

Comment: @molbdnilo: improving this version makes little sense, as you can solve the problem without any binary search.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I think we _do need_ that `*loc+nums[i]==k`, otherwise this test case fails: `nums = [1, 3, 5, 8]` `k = 7`.  I think that's because if the element (k-nums[i]) is not found, `lower_bound` returns the next one.

Comment: @Someone No, [it works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/594594ebbff454a7).

Comment: @molbdnilo, oh, along with starting the search at `std::begin(nums)+i+1`, yep. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in comments in worst case the code iterates over the array and performs binary search on the array in each step. And so the complexity of that operation is O(Nlog(N)).

> I use distance(), which, as I understand, is an O(n) operation by itself.

Actually it is O(1) when used on std::vector::iterator because it is a *LegacyRandomAccessIterator* ( [Is std::next for vector O(n) or O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586847/is-stdnext-for-vector-on-or-o1) ) and for such iterators [std::distance is O(1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance#Complexity) and so it doesn't participate in our calculation.

Comment: That makes sense.  I took slower to mean that they had worse complexity, so I wanted to check.